# Azure Devops ApplyPatch Error when trying to run job

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

I'm attempting to migrate an outdated 2012 R2 TFS server over to a 2019 server with Azure Devops installed on it. I've installed all of the prerequiites for the new server, and have SQL Server 2017 installed as well as Azure Devops version 17.153.29522.3 (AzureDevOps2019.Update1.1) installed. The databases migrated over without any issue and I was able to setup Devops without issue. However, when I attempt to start the collection, I receive an error message:
[Default collection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYJHD.png)

This similar thing happened when I initially setup Azure Devops and added the Project Collection from the old production server. The issue appears to be an ApplyPatch Servicing Activity that needs to be run on the Project Collection. However, when I try to run the Patch, I receive the following error message:
[Project Collection ApplyPatch Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cad9.png)

When I view the log entry for this job, the line where the error occurs states ":[2024-03-04 23:15:19Z][Error] Could not find dataspace with category Build and identifier XXXXXXX". I'm unsure what the issue could be for this error and how to resolve it. I attempted to get assistance from the Azure Devops Community from Microsoft but was not able to get it resolved.I ran into this same issue on a previous iteration of a trial setup and was able to fix it after reading a different article from a user that had the same issue on Microsoft's community forums. However, trying to access the article, it appears to have been taken down due to Microsoft changing the way their forums work so I can't look at it to apply the fix I did previously. I believe the solution was to remove the affected dataspace. As a general Systems Administrator with just a basic knowledge of SQL datbases, I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that. I'm hoping someone may have some insight to how to resolve the issue, or even provide some insight as to what the error means as a lot of my research has come up with no fruitful results.

I've followed the guidelines set by Microsoft to know that the requirements are met on the new server and the upgrade paths are sufficient.

Attempted a reinstall of Azure Devops on upgrade server, believing that may fix the issue. This was unsuccessful.

Comment: I'd recommend contacting Microsoft support.